# Android studio: how to show position of data in ascending order from firebase using recycler view

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 4 data displayed in my `RecyclerView`.  I want to show its position in ascending order like the first data is in number 1 then next one is 2 and so on.

Each data has its number according to its position in `RecyclerView` Anyone can know how to do this?

I'm using Firebase.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse your recycler view layout data when assigning a layout manager to recycler view:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CONTEXT,OREIENTATION,true));
```

where the third parameter (true) indicates wether items be in reverse order or not.

for-example:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true));
```

in this case the data is shown in reverse order otherwise if false data is shown in normal order.